# Network Error Django Backend to React Frontend

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm trying to connect my Django backend to a React Frontend using axios to access the api endpoint. I have tested the api using curl to see if I receive a json of the test data, it is fine. I have opened up the endpoint so that it does not need authentication. But I keep on getting this error in my javascript console:

edit: for to say that I am running the api and frontend on my computer

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

Test.js- Test component to test out feeding backend to frontend. I would like to console log the data but only catch the error.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      messages:[],
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/message/?format=json')
      .then(res=> {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(error =>{
        console.log(error);
      });
}
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>
          Message:
        </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Test;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to setup CORS on my django api. The issue was not with my front end but by backend not being setup properly. Whenever you have api request from a different server you have to setup CORS on the backend.

Comment: provide code examples homie